# lumen 5.7 dusterio/lumen-passport fails on php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

After creating a fresh **laravel/lumen 5.7** and installing [dusterio/lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) package and following the instructions on there site:

I get the following error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = )
>
> In Connection.php line 452:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Here is my config file:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}



$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

 $app->withFacades();

 $app->withEloquent();


$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);


 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ]);



$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);



$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

I have done the same **lumen 5.6** and it works well.

Please assist.

Comment: can you share the configuration file?

Comment: i have included the config file

Comment: Weird but it looks like the `engine` is not passed? `engine = `  also can you try commenting out `$app->withFacades();`

Comment: i have tried that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to install and migrate for tables without installing the passport package?

Answer (score 0):

Since the migration seems to try running, it may be because your db server does not support utf8mb4, try setting your database config to :

```
            'charset' => 'utf8',
```

Instead of :

```
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
```